# Sitecore permission to Move item for role which Doesn't have delete permissions

Tags: security, role-management, permissions, editor-user-permissions

There is a requirement that the client wants the basic Author role to have the rights to move the items in the content tree. But, that role is denied the rights to delete. From what I understand, Sitecore needs delete and create access for the user to move items as it considers it as deleting at one place and re-creating again.
Is there a way to configure this in Sitecore ?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22224/allowing-custom-role-to-move-items

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below Sitecore Community blog:

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/who-can-move-items-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms

> To move an item, one needs at least read access to the source and
> destination items. In fact, one needs the delete access right for the
> source item and the create access right for the destination item.

By adding `Create` and `Delete` access right on the source and target item, the source item can be moved successfully (using the Drag and Drop method).

In order for `Move To` context menu to show up, the user need to have `Read` permission on: `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Context Menues/Default/Copying`

So in order for me to fix go to your workflow, assigned security details, and ticked the Create and Delete for this role. Then checked this with access viewer. Also needed to grant permission on the `workflow:delete` item